# Regex for htaccess redirect (with exceptions!)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am looking forward to redirect hundreds of URL belonging to the path `https://example.com/fragen/`, for example:

```
https://www.example.com/fragen/amazonerstattungen/
https://www.example.com/fragen/sonderbetriebsvermoegen/
https://www.example.com/fragen/troedel/
```

to a single URL like `https://www.example.com/wiki/`

Could you please suggest me the correct regex expression to be included in the .htaccess to attain this goal?

Besides, a few URLs belonging to the `/fragen/` path should be redirected separately.
I suppose that these redirects should precede the regex expression in the code block in object. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite, near the top of your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Specific Redirects
RewriteRule ^fragen/specific-url$ /somewhere-else [R=302,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^fragen/another-url$ /another-url [R=302,NC,L]

# Redirect everything else in "/fragen/" to "/wiki/"
RewriteRule ^fragen/ /wiki/ [R=302,L,NC]
```

The regex `^fragen/` matches any URL-path that starts `fragen/`. Note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` directive does not start with a slash.

And yes, as you suggest, specific redirects need to precede the generalised redirect.

Note that these are 302 (temporary) redirects. Always test first with 302s to avoid potential caching issues. Only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed it works as intended.

*Aside:* This might not have the SEO benefit you are hoping. A many-to-one redirect like this is often seen as a soft-404 by search engines. And users often *bounce*. It is often preferable to implement a custom 404 response and offer an explanation to the user where the page has gone.

Comment: thank you very, very much, @MrWhite. your answer is on point to 100%

Comment: Sorry again, I tested your solution and this is what I got: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: @RomanTrushanov Sorry, there was a typo in the last line. It should read `RewriteRule ...` (the same as the previous lines), not `RedirectRule ...`! (There is no such directive as "RedirectRule" - hence the error.)